# R vector - find the count of max positive results which can be obtained from difference of two vectors

Tags: r, vector, count

I have two vector's

```
A = c(28427,19877,30709,18527,17409,14758,20873,18458,28587,17751,21672)
```

```
B = c(407,2019,10539,15430,17994,20213,21865,26217,26619,30558,31674)
```

without using any external library, I need to order A and B in such a way to get the max possible count of +ve results gained after differencing these two vectors.

Here the result should be 9 as there are maximum 9 results which will turn out to be positive.

I tried using divide and conquer, but it takes lot of time to solve and I am not getting the optimal logic.

Comment: Can you please improve your question with addition of: 1. what you've tried & the output you've got; 2. Expected output? (not as images, but in codes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = c(28427,19877,30709,18527,17409,14758,20873,18458,28587,17751,21672)
b = c(407,2019,10539,15430,17994,20213,21865,26217,26619,30558,31674)

a_sorted <- sort(a, decreasing = T)
b_sorted <- sort(b, decreasing = T)

out <- data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = 3))
names(out) <- c("a", "b", "d")
k <- 1
j <- 1
for (i in 1:length(a)) {
  while (j <= length(a)) {
    d <- a_sorted[i] - b_sorted[j]
    # message(sprintf("i = %d; j = %d k = %d;\taa[i] = %s\tbb[j] = %s\td[k] = %s", i, j, k, a_sorted[i], b_sorted[j], d))
    if (d > 0) {
      out[k,] <- c(a_sorted[i], b_sorted[j], d)
      k <- k + 1
      j <- j + 1
      break
    }
    j <- j + 1
  }
}

out
#>       a     b     d
#> 1 30709 30558   151
#> 2 28587 26619  1968
#> 3 28427 26217  2210
#> 4 21672 20213  1459
#> 5 20873 17994  2879
#> 6 19877 15430  4447
#> 7 18527 10539  7988
#> 8 18458  2019 16439
#> 9 17751   407 17344
```